# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type viewmodel. DateTime content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on WEBAPI on .net framework 4.5.
when i  am calling webapi to get data from  MVC controller then i am getting below error.could you please suggest how to resolve this problem.can i use other way  instead of using my current approach implementation.

**System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type viewmodel. DateTime content '2016-06-15T12:12:25' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON. ---> System.FormatException:**

***my code base***

object resultView = client.UploadString(url, "POST", jsonString);

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Responseobject));
                                       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultView.ToString()));
                                       Responseobject objLocalResponse = new Responseobject();
                                       objLocalResponseobject = (Responseobject)ser.ReadObject(ms);
```

Comment: I'm gathering this is in the WebApi method.  What does the client code posting the jsonstring parameter look like?  Is it valid json?

Comment: thanks for reply.actualy above code written inside 
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
--code here
}

Comment: A couple of suggestions and questions. Instead of  webclient I would use HttpClient.  I would also use JSON.Net to deserialize your response.  Finally are you 100% certain the response is json?  Web api by DEFAULT returns XML.  You can check this by looking at the content-type returned in the response